# Angular doesn't return the expected value

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, http, angular7

I'm a bit new to Angular (7). I'm trying to retrieve the status code when I do an HTTP request. Here's the code I use in a service :

```
checkIfSymbolExists() {
     return this.http.get(this.url, { observe: 'response' })
      .subscribe(response => {
        return response.status;
      });
  }
```

And I use the returned value in a method in one of my components like this :

```
onSubmit() {
    console.log(this.stocks.checkIfSymbolExists());
}
```

I was expecting a number to be returned, but instead I have an object :

```
Subscriber {closed: false, _parent: null, _parents: null, _subscriptions: Array(1), syncErrorValue: null, …}
closed: true
destination: SafeSubscriber {closed: true, _parent: null, _parents: null, _subscriptions: null, syncErrorValue: null, …}
isStopped: true
syncErrorThrowable: true
syncErrorThrown: false
syncErrorValue: null
_parent: null
_parentSubscription: null
_parents: null
_subscriptions: null
__proto__: Subscription
```

When, instead of simply returning `response.status` I do a console.log of it, I do get the 200 status code as expected (a number, and not an object).

Any ideas why it's not the same behavior when returning the value of `response.status` as shown here ? Thanks.

Comment: What is your backend API code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing it the wrong way. Here's the correct way of doing this:

First you return a mapped response from `http.get` instead of `subscribe`ing from there. So you'll need to use `.pipe(map(...))` instead of `subscribe`:

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
...
checkIfSymbolExists() {
  return this.http.get(this.url, { observe: 'response' })
    .pipe(
      map(res => (res.status === 200))
    );
}
```

And then you return the observable from `checkIfSymbolExists` and then `subscribe` to it in the `onSubmit` method:

```
onSubmit() {
  this.stocks.checkIfSymbolExists()
    .subscribe(res => console.log(res));
  // This should print true if status is 200. false instead.
}
```

**Explaination:**

The responsibility of your service method `checkIfSymbolExists()` is to give the Component what it wants. So basically your Component doesn't need to know where exactly is your service getting this data from. It just needs to get a `boolean` on subscribing to the `Observable` returned by `checkIfSymbolExists()`

Now the `checkIfSymbolExists()` method gets response and you've also added an option to `observe` the complete response. `map` is just an Rxjs operator that will transform the response. Inside `map` what we're doing is checking for `res.status` which we will get because we have `observe`d the response by doing `{ observe: 'response' }`

Now the `map` will return whatever is returned by the comparison operator `===` which will return `true` if `status` is `200` and `false` otherwise.

Hope this gives you a better understanding.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What if I wanna check the status code *inside* of the service's method ? Like this : 

response => {
        if (response.status === 200) {
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      }

(edit : sorry for the indentation)

Comment: You are *very* fast XD. And it worked ! Thank you so much !

I'm not exctly sure what all those methods do, but I can see that I still have a lot to learn ^^

Comment: @tomfl, I've added the explanation. Hope that helps you understand a bit of what's happening.

Comment: Thank you very much. Tell me if I'm wrong, but the reason why we are `subscribe`ing to the response (?) in the component (and not the service) is because the response is asynchronous, meaning that the rest of the code is executed and only then the reponse is sent (after it was loaded from the server), right ?

Comment: Yes. You can say that. Whatever you write inside the `subscribe` block will get called only once the response is received and then `map`ped by the service.